# Not able to open port between windows 10 and locally hosted Ubuntu VM created on Hyper-v

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, port, hyper-v, docker

This started when I was trying to use docker swarm join from the ubuntu vm (created using hyper-v) to my windows 10 docker engine. I am using the default port 2377. I keep getting connection refused error.

Now I am just trying to **telnet over port 2377** from ubuntu vm to windows 10 or from windows to ubuntu and it is failing on both ways. while telnet is working fine on port 80.

I added inbound and outbound rules for both protocols udp and tcp on windows 10, and used the command "ufw allow 2377/tcp" on the ubuntu vm and also opened the port for both tcp and udp. Still it is not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody comes here.
after some analysis I discovered that there is a problem in docker engine itself. The port is not open.
Because I tried creating a simple app that listens on port 2377, and I ran it on the windows 10 machine then I was able to connect to it from the VM.
Also after running the swarm mode, I run the command "netstat -ab" on windows 10, and I can't see port 2377 listed.
I opened a topic on docker forums but no one has responded yet.
https://forums.docker.com/t/swarm-mode-is-not-working-on-windows-10/72761